# Applscript *.type

Tags: macos, applescript

I know I'm being an idiot here... Where am I going wrong? is it neccicary to use sudo rm -f? and why is the *.cr2 not working?

```
 tell application "System Events"
   try
    do shell script "rm /Users/splashretouch8/Pictures/SplashNW/Capture/*.cr2"
   end try
  end tell
```

Comment: Why are you telling system events to run that command? "do shell script" is an applescript command and should not be run inside any "tell application" block of code. Try it this way and see if you get better results.

Comment: What happens if you just run the shell script itself from the Terminal? If it fails, it'll tell you why it's failed, and you can experiment with how to get it to work (do you need sudo? -f? whatever…), and then put it back into your applescript wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
set theFolder to alias ("/Users/splashretouch8/Pictures/SplashNW/Capture/" as POSIX file)
tell application "Finder" to delete (every file of theFolder whose name contains ".cr2")
```

Or

```
do shell script "cd '/Users/splashretouch8/Pictures/SplashNW/Capture/' ; rm *.cr2"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this as a backup option. I'm trying to keep things away from the front end apps for now

Answer (score 0):

Put a "`\`" character in front of the asterix (e.g. "`\*.cr2`") and see if it works better for you.

Myself, I think using "rm" is way dangerous in an Applescript.  It might be smarter to move files you want to remove into the Trash.

Comment: no dice. and i am looking to rm. i run this script after i make selects. no second retries, hah.